# import qualified as nothing - not an error

Tags: haskell

This is as much to add something searchable for the next poor sap, but I'd be interested in knowing *why* it's not an error.

I needed the FromRow typeclass from postgresql-simple but forgot it was in its own package.

```
import qualified Database.Postgresql.Simple as P
```

oops - just want the .FromRow sub-module

```
import qualified Database.Postgresql.Simple.FromRow
```

Of course, didn't need it qualified, so stripped the name off the end. However, I forgot to remove the "qualified" keyword.

Generates an error, and much headscratching from me, as I fail to spot the typo:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `FromRow'
Perhaps you meant `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow.FromRow' (imported from Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow)
```

So - just so this is a question, why is an unnamed qualified import not an error? Is it useful for something, or am I the first person stupid enough to make this mistake?

Comment: It's shouting you the problem along with the solution right in the face: "Perhaps you meant `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow.FromRow'‽"

Comment: Ah, but I did mean exactly that. And had I taken the "qualified" out my usage and meaning would have coincided. The problem was "you left the qualified keyword in, numbskull" and nothing else. Classic case where the error explains from the computer's point of view, not the human's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`qualified` and `as` are independent features of imports.

`qualified` says that the names become available only under *qualified* names (i.e. names that include the module name).

`as` simply changes the module name which is used to qualify the names.

So, there are 4 different ways to import a module:

- `import Database.Postgresql.Simple` — both qualified and unqualified names are visible; the qualified ones should be qualified with `Database.Postgresql.Simple`
- `import Database.Postgresql.Simple as P` — both qualified and unqualified names are visible; the qualified ones should be qualified with `P`
- `import qualified Database.Postgresql.Simple` — only qualified names are visible and they should be qualified with `Database.Postgresql.Simple`
- `import qualified Database.Postgresql.Simple as P` — only qualified names are visible and they should be qualified with `P`